# How should I organize test cases for multiple web drivers in my Python Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, project-organization

In my PyCharm editor I have a test_suite.py file and a functions.py file. In the functions file I have written a Class to establish a Chrome webdriver and a separate class to establish the Firefox webdriver. In this file I am currently copy/pasting every function for the firefox section to the chrome section as well and I am worried that this will create a massive page of test cases that is not properly organized.

Functions.py file looks like:

```
import libraries
from libraries import *
import ini
from ini import *

class ChromeBase(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.base_url = baseurl
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)

   def testcase1(self):
    global resultfail
    resultfail = 'unable to do what you want'
    try:self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("sign in").click()
    except failed() as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

  def testcase2(self):
    self.signin('test@user.com', 'xxx')

  def testcase3(self):
    self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1020)
    self.signin('test2@user.com', 'xxx')

class baseline(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Downloads\\"))
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv, application/octet-stream')
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    self.base_url = baseurl
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)

  def testcase1(self):
    global resultfail
    resultfail = 'unable to do what you want'
    try:self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("sign in").click()
    except failed() as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

  def testcase2(self):
    self.signin('test@user.com', 'xxx')

  def testcase3(self):
    self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1020)
    self.signin('test2@user.com', 'xxx')
```

And in my test_suite file I am calling the different webdrivers as such:

```
class TestCase(baseline):
  def test_case1(self):
    print('testcase1')
    self.driver.get(self.base_url)
    self.testcase1()
    self.testcase2()
    self.testcase3()

class TestCase(ChromeBase):
  def test_case1(self):
    print('testcase1')
    self.driver.get(self.base_url)
    self.testcase1()
    self.testcase2()
    self.testcase3()
```

Can I organize the project in my PyCharm editor to be easily readable and to call on different Webdrivers in a neat manner?

How would I go about doing this so that when I click the green Play button i can manage whether to run the cases for all web browsers or for just a specific web browser?

Cheers

Comment: why separate classes for *firefox* and *chrome*? why not just one class? with this approach what will you do when you will have to run tests on another 2 browsers.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang, I'm not sure I understand how to combine the separate classes. What if I only wanted to run Firefox tests and not Chrome/other browsers?

Comment: Create one class which returns driver object based on string you pass.